# Final concat data shape not matching with the actual data shape

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i am doing a subsequent filtration of the data basis on the negative value and count. However after doing operation when i concat the filtered data back to the orginal form, then i am not getting the actual data shape

Below is the code for your reference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B':[6, 7, -2, -3, 10],'C':[9, -3, -7, 6, 10],'D':[-4,6,5,7,-2]})
df.shape
####################################

negative_vlaue = df[(df['B']<=-1)|(df['C']<=-1)|(df['D']<=-1)]
inv_countone=df[df['A']<=1]

##############################################

mydata=df[(df['B']>-1)|(df['C']>-1)|(df['D']>-1)]
mydata=mydata[mydata['A']>1]
################################################

finaldata=pd.concat([mydata,negative_vlaue,inv_countone])

finaldata.shape
```

Comment: Seem like the 3 dataframes that you finally concat are not mutually exclusive in data.

Comment: How will i confirm that the final concat data is the right table even though the actual shape and the final data shape are different. Is there a better way to code it

Comment: From the index of `finaldata`, you can see from the index `1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0` which rows are they originated from the original df

Comment: can you please help me with the code

Comment: @Yogesh Govindan, can you add your desired outcome in the question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, what you need to do is **[`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html)** together your *mydata* and *negative_vlaue* dataframes, and then use **[`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)** to bring in your *inv_countone*:

```
final_data = (mydata.add(negative_vlaue)).combine_first(inv_countone)
```

Prints:

```
>>> final_data

      A     B     C     D
0   1.0   6.0   9.0  -4.0
1   4.0  14.0  -6.0  12.0
2   6.0  -4.0 -14.0  10.0
3   8.0  -6.0  12.0  14.0
4  10.0  20.0  20.0  -4.0
```

I can't be fully confident that this is what you need as you did not specify your desired outcome, but this utilises the calculations you listed above and keeps the initial shape.

The reason that your **[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.concat.html)** is not the solution here, is because it appends the datasets together, row-wise as it is the default:

```
>>> finaldata_concat = pd.concat([mydata,negative_vlaue,inv_countone])
>>> len(mydata) +len(negative_vlaue) + len(inv_countone) == len(finaldata_concat)

Out[171]: True
```

Comment: sorry to tell you that i was not checking the output of the final_data, but i can see from your output that  the column information is not matching with my main source data i.e df

Comment: Okay let's correct it. Can you make it a bit clearer on what is it you are looking for exactly? What is the exact output that you are looking for?

Comment: first filter out the negative values and create a dataframe

Comment: but then how come in your last command you bring back the negative values? i.e. ```finaldata=pd.concat([mydata,negative_vlaue,inv_countone])```

Comment: Also what do you mean by 'just filter out negative values'? Do I need to exclude the row that contains negative values? The column that contains negative values? Do you want to make the negative values positive values?

Comment: negative_value dataset-- by filtering the negative dataset,mydata is the positive dataset, invoice_countone is the dataset having only column A having 1.. after that we will combine filtered dataset and should match my source dataset

Comment: the inv_countone also has a negative value though. in column D.

Comment: negative_vlaue = df[(df['B']<=-1)|(df['C']<=-1)|(df['D']<=-1)] this is the condition i used

Comment: one option i saw is to remove duplicates then i will precisely come back to the exact data

Answer (score 0):

`negative_vlaue` selects `row 0`, `inv_countone` also selects `row 0`, so in your `finaldata` you have `row 0` two times. that is why shapes are different.

If you need the same shape, think about your filtering conditions to be exclusive as @SeaBean suggests in comments